# Problem when enabling vb.net checkboxlist using javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

On page load, im disable a checkboxlist, when the users selects a radiobutton, it calls a java function to enable the entire checkbox list. I've tried many ways to enable the checkboxlist without success. Am i missing something?

```
                            <td><asp:radiobutton id="radApprove" runat="server" Groupname="radDisp" Text="Approved" onclick="radioButtons(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>Method of Validation:
                            <asp:checkboxlist id="chkMethodUsed" runat="server" 
                                style="margin-top: 0px">
                            <asp:ListItem>AD</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>ESM</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>EWT</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>SB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>WorkOrder</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:checkboxlist>
```

None of these  java statements below will enable the checkbox list

```
                if (pobjButton.id == "radApprove") 
            {
                var a = document.getElementById('<%=chkMethodUsed.ClientID%>')
                a.removeAttribute('disabled');
                a.attributes.disabled = false
                a.disabled = false
                a.parentNode.removeAttribute('disabled');
                document.getElementsByName('chkMethodUsed').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('chkMethodUsed').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('chkMethodUsed').removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
```

Comment: Just a detail. The code you show is not "Java" but "Javascript". For SO users that is so confusional as those languages are totally different.

Comment: have you dropped a breakpoint or tried displaying an alert within the javascript function you are having issues getting to work? it could be it is not even getting to that code.

Answer (score 0):

Start from here:

.Aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radDisable" runat="server" GroupName="radDisp" Text="Disable" onclick="radioButtons(this)" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radEnable" runat="server" GroupName="radDisp" Text="Enable" onclick="radioButtons(this)" />

        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkMethodUsed" runat="server"
            Style="margin-top: 0px">
            <asp:ListItem>AD</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>ESM</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>EWT</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>SB</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>WorkOrder</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>

    </div>
</form>
```

.js:

```
function radioButtons(pobjButton) {

    var parentChecks = document.getElementById('chkMethodUsed');
    var checks = parentChecks.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    try {
        switch (pobjButton.id) {
            case "radDisable":

                for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
                    checks[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                break;

            case "radEnable":
                for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
                    checks[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
                break;

        }

    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi G3nt_M3caj, thanks for the response, however it still wont enable for me. I dont seem to have this issue with textbox, but for this checkbox list I cant figure out why it wont work. The try/catch statement doesnt error, the code runs through like it should when i step through it. I did notice that when i look at the attribute value for checks[i] during the for loop, all the checkboxes show null as value for attribute. Does that sound correct?

Comment: It’s probably there is caused a submit by some your radios and the page is refreshed avery click. Put a Stop in Page.Load if there is called after you click on one of those radio buttons. The code above without other code works. Take a try without changing my code